# JavaScript - For Loop to add days in a month object - moment.js

Tags: javascript, for-loop, momentjs

I'm trying to assign every day in the month to my object but I'm only get the last day of each month. How should I do to get full month assigned?

```
function loopRange (startDate, range) {
   let fromDate = moment(startDate)
   let toDate = moment(startDate).add(range, 'month')
   let dates = {}

   for (let m = moment(fromDate); m.diff(toDate, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
        dates['month_' + m.format('MM')] = {
           'date': m.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        }
    }

    return dates
}
```

Result I want:

```
dates = {month_11: ['2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', ...]}
```

Comment: What are you expecting the result to look like? Should the `date` property contain an array of dates?

Comment: I want every day in the `dates['month_' + m.format('MM')]`object. Only get the last one now

Comment: And if not, how do you expect to get more than one date in the object?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You're complaining that you're only getting the last date. Where do you expect to put more than one date in a single object property?

Comment: I'm looping based on the `range` in `toDate`. `range` in this case is 2, that means loop two months forwards.

Comment: Please just show what you expect the final result to look like. I know there should be two months, but where do you expect to put multiple dates in each month?

Comment: `{['2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', ...]}` is not valid syntax. Everything inside `{}` has to be in `key: value` format.

Comment: An array is just surrounded by `[]`, not `{}` as well.

Comment: I've updated my question now with the result. That's the problem, I'm stuck, it seems that I'm overwriting the key for every month and that's the major problem here.

Comment: David's answer shows how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get only the last day because your for-loop advance in day interval.

However, when assign to dic of `dates` you put the month as the key - so each iteration (within the same month) override the previous key with the new day -> so you get only yhe lasy day of the months...

If you want to have all dates in the time-range as array elements divide on month keys you can use the following code:

```
for (let m = moment(fromDate); m.diff(toDate, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) 
{
    let month_key = 'month_' + m.format('MM'); 
    if (!dates.hasOwnProperty(month_key))
        dates[month_key] = []; 
    dates[month_key].push(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
```

Comment: If he uses the full format as the key then the key will be the same as the value. What's the point of that?

Comment: Thanks, that make some sense to me! I would to have the month as key and not the full format of the date.

Comment: @Barmar - I agree. But it look like this was OP intension -> get the value of the dates. I will edit the answer to have sub-json in each month that contain all the day but I'm not sure this was the original request

Comment: Or maybe he wants an array of all the dates in the month, like `{month_11: ['2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', ...]}`

Comment: That exactly was I meant by my last comment - will edit the answer

Comment: @Barmar exactly, It's on the point of what I'm trying to do here

Comment: @nahoj Put that in the question.

Comment: @nahoj Does now my post answer your question?